# HDP 2.2 Sandbox Could not find SQOOP directory

Tags: hadoop, sandbox, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I was following the tutorial

http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/import-microsoft-sql-server-hortonworks-sandbox-using-sqoop/

I am unable to find the /usr/lib/sqoop/lib.
I could see Sqoop running in the sandbox. Just not able to find the folder to drop the drivers.

Where else I could place the jdbc driver? Also where is the installation directory for sqoop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in `/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/sqoop/lib`

Answer (score 0):

run below command at sandbox root to locate sqoop

```
find . / "sqoop"
```

Comment: This command actually listed each and every occurrence of the word "scoop" that is not intended.